# How to program in a type system that mismatches Haskell's System-Fw?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-systems

I'm studying optimal implementations of the λ-calculus. There is a particular subset of lambda terms that is very efficient. It corresponds to the type system of **Elementary Affine Logic** with fixed points. In order to test my implementations of that algorithm, I have to write moderately complex terms on that system. This is difficult without a infrastructure. I have to use the untyped lambda calculus and then manually add the types; no checking, unification, no type errors.

One idea would be to write programs in Haskell - taking benefit from its mature type-checker - and then translate to EAL. Unfortunately, there is a mismatch between System-Fw and EAL. For example, you can't express Scott-encoded ADTs in Haskell without `newtype`, due to the lack of a type-level `fix`. Moreover, Haskell is a complex language, and writing a `Haskell->EAl` compiler would not be trivial.

Is there any quick/dirty way to get a working type checker/inferencer/unifier for that system - or at least something close enough - without having to program it all myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the quickest and easiest way is to embed your system into Haskell as an EDSL.  The [finally, tagless](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/) approach may be ideal and there's an [example of encoding a linear type system](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/#linear) with it.  In particular, I'd recommend using the [HOAS variation by Jeff Polakow](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-March/107215.html).  This will give you syntax like:

```
*Main> :t eval $ llam $ \x -> add x (int 1)
eval $ llam $ \x -> add x (int 1) :: Int -<> Int
```

which isn't too terrible.  One aspect of the finally, tagless approach is that you can can have multiple interpretations for the same term, so you can have an interpretation that translates the term to some AST representing EAL, or have an interpretation that performs some additional typechecking if you aren't able to capture all of it in Haskell's type system.

Comment: But I'm not sure how this solve my problem of not having type errors, inference, unification, etc. - although I guess it couldn't be possible without writing those myself?

Comment: Looking at [Principal Typing for Lambda Calculus in Elementary Affine Logic](http://www.di.unito.it/~ronchi/papers/EA-typingFI.pdf) it looks like a simple fragment of a completely ordinary linear lambda calculus.  In fact, it looks like exactly [the language Oleg defined](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/#linear).  So my comment at the end about doing "additional typechecking" is unnecessary.  You would completely rely on Haskell's type errors/inference/unification.  Admittedly, the type error messages will be not the best.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?

Comment: A remaining issue is your desire for equi-recursive types. Depending on your needs, you could just add the types you want as "primitives".  A bit more extreme is that you could embed Haskell values and types into your language.  Alternatively, you could switch to O'Caml which supports equi-recursive types with the `-rectypes` flag.  Oleg describes using the finally, tagless approach in O'Caml as well albeit not for the linear lambda calculus example.